# Yandex-Tank TLS requests with phantom

Tags: ssl, tls1.2, google-cloud-functions, yandex-tank

How can I setup yandex-tank to tell phantom to use TLS encryption instead of SSL? I already found that phantom can be configured to used TLS via it's startup parameter `--ssl-protocol=tlsv1`, but I don't know how can I pass this parameter when using yndex-tank configs.

[link to phantom config issue with startup cli parameter](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12165)

Here is the part of **load.ini** file which is configuring phantom load generator.

```
[phantom]
address=%(env_url)s:443
ssl=1
writelog=1
rps_schedule=step(1, 70, 5, 15s) line(1, 70, 1m)
header_http=1.1
uris=/
```

I'm trying to test Google Cloud Functions directly just to confirm breaks in connection, and as it turned out, GCF using TLS encryption. I tested this with curl, so now I need to configure it somehow using tank.

Answer (score 0):

1) Correct link to load generator - https://github.com/yandex-load/phantom, which uses openssl library.

2) Checked [openssl's SSLv23_client_method](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/ssl/SSLv23_client_method.html) which is used in [phantom code](https://github.com/yandex-load/phantom/blob/master/pd/ssl/ssl.C#L132)

> These are the general-purpose version-flexible SSL/TLS methods. The
>   actual protocol version used will be negotiated to the highest version
>   mutually supported by the client and the server.

So, just make sure that target's webserver and openssl on load server both support TLS.

3) Option ssl=1 just says to phantom "use tls encryption" and doesn't  specify proto version

Comment: I answered on the russion SO. Sorry for cross sites duplicates :)